# Visual Studio WPF Designer Right Click Context Menu Lacks "Properties" Option

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I noticed in Visual Studio, while working in a WPF environment, that if I right click on a control within the design-view the context menu does not contain a "Properties" option for the control that I right clicked on. Here is a picture:

[image]

This is really bothering me and hindering my workflow because I am quite used to the Winforms Designer supporting the right-click-open properties feature. So my question is: **how do I add "Open Properties for the current control" to the designer context menu?**

Answer (score 2):

Select the control in designer, and press F4 - it shows you the Properties window for that control.

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative would be to open "View", find "properties" and pin it to the side of Visual Studio

Comment: I have been doing this. I find it annoying because I still catch myself right clicking and looking for the option.